# how to change number format with Gijgo Jquery?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

is this jQuery has a code for change number format to currency ?, i have read all the documentation on his web site and still not found

[HARGA is not currency format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11xtB.png)

```
columns: [
    { field: 'HARGA', title: 'HARGA'},
],
```

i want to change the format number from 000000 to 000,000.00 
i already try using [Format="{0:n2}"] but its not working ,

Comment: There are no numbers in your example. Can you edit your question to show the data you need to modify and what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that would be best if you use the column renderer in order to format the value. You can find an examples about it at http://gijgo.com/grid/configuration/column.renderer